# Python/Pandas : Avoiding for loops but making queries with condition on dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner with python/pandas. I have a dataset where i have two "big" tables : the table of the messages posted by users and the table of the users with an user_id linking the two tables.

I would like to analyze the text for each user. Each user can have several messages. So i guess i need to do queries with each user_id as the condition. I wanted to avoid making a query to the database for each user because i thought it might be slower so i put everything in two dataframes.

My questions are :

- Is there a way to vectorize to avoid doing something like this ? (the code might not be working but i just want to tell you the idea of the loop)

```
for index,user in users.iterrow():
    userMessages = df.loc[df['user_id'] == user_id]
    # do the analysis i want on the text of the user
```

- Is it ok to put all my data in dataframes if my RAM is big enough or using the SQL DB would be beneficial ?

Thank you

The dataframes would look like something very simple like that for now since i want to analyze the text first

```
              user_id                                                                                                                                      text
0          1029413485                                                             text1
1           413132646                   text2
2  784769137956495360                   text3
3          3179636930                    text 4
4          1045723741                    text5


    user_id          counter1        counter2 
0  95487821              259            533                  
1  95491989             3527           2970                  
2  95498383                0              6                  
3  95500356              422           1729                  
4  95502233              276            250
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your two dataframes (i.e. first 5 rows of each)? You can do `print(df.head())` to show the first 5 rows.

Comment: I added it. I just modified the values since i don't think it is important.

Comment: _Is there a way to vectorize to avoid doing something like this ? (the code might not be working but i just want to tell you the idea of the loop)_ Yes, by reading the Pandas docs. _Is it ok to put all my data in dataframes if my RAM is big enough or using the SQL DB would be beneficial ?_ I don't think we can really answer that with so little information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we will do this in a few steps.

Assuming we have dataframes like this:

```
users = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'user_age' : [22, 23, 24, 25],
})

messages = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id' : [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'messages' : ['message 1', 'message 2', 'message 3', 'message 4'],
})
```

We can then do this:

```
# Step 1) set indecies to user_id:
users = users.set_index('user_id')
messages = messages.set_index('user_id')

# Step 2) join dataframes (this will join on index):
users_messages = users.join(messages)

# Step 3) reset index on joined dataframe:
users_messages = users_messages.reset_index()

# Step 4) query for specific user:
result = users_messages.loc[users_messages.user_id == 1]
```